# module 'django.db.backends.utils' has no attribute 'typecast_decimal'

Tags: django, sybase, sqlanydb

When I run

`python manage.py  inspectdb --database=sybase_database`

it ends with error message:

`Database.register_converter(Database.DT_DECIMAL, util.typecast_decimal) AttributeError: module 'django.db.backends.utils' has no attribute 'typecast_decimal'`

```
$ pip freeze
certifi==2021.10.8
chardet==3.0.4
defusedxml==0.7.1
Django==2.2.4
django-allauth==0.40.0
django-bootstrap-form==3.4
django-bootstrap3==15.0.0
django-crispy-forms==1.7.2
django-crudbuilder==0.2.7
django-debug-toolbar==1.10.1
django-filter==2.2.0
django-mssql-backend==2.8.1
django-tables2==2.4.1
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==2.1.1
oauthlib==3.1.1
pyodbc==4.0.32
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python3-openid==3.2.0
pytz==2021.3
requests==2.21.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.16.0
sqlany-django==1.13
sqlanydb==1.0.11
sqlparse==0.4.2
urllib3==1.24.3
zipp==3.6.0
```

`Ubuntu 18.04`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlany-django` only supports up to Django 1.8.5 (Django 1.7.0 for `inspectdb` command).
It is no longer maintained; it was last updated in May 2016.

You can patch for later versions of Django in manage.py or an [`AppConfig`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig).

```py
# Django >= 2.0, for sqlany_django/base.py
import decimal
from django.db.backends import utils
utils.typecast_decimal = decimal.Decimal

# Django >= 1.11, for BaseDatabaseWrapper
from sqlany_django.base import DatabaseWrapper
DatabaseWrapper.client_class = lambda self, connection: None
DatabaseWrapper.creation_class = lambda self, connection: None
DatabaseWrapper.features_class = lambda self, connection: None
DatabaseWrapper.introspection_class = lambda self, connection: None
DatabaseWrapper.ops_class = lambda self, connection: None

# Django >= 1.7.1, for inspectdb
from django.db.backends import utils
from sqlany_django import base
class CursorWrapper(base.CursorWrapper, utils.CursorWrapper):
    pass
base.CursorWrapper = CursorWrapper
```

References:

- https://github.com/django/django/pull/2154 regarding `CursorWrapper`
- https://github.com/django/django/pull/7206 regarding `DatabaseWrapper`
- https://github.com/django/django/pull/8889 regarding `typecast_decimal`
- https://github.com/sqlanywhere/sqlany-django/pull/15 regarding `typecast_decimal`
- https://sqlanywhere-forum.sap.com/questions/37563/sqlany-django-driver-upgrade-to-django-32 requesting an update to `sqlany_django` (unanswered as of this post)

---

Stack traces:

1. Regarding `DatabaseWrapper`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/path/to/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 40, in handle_inspection
    connection = connections[options['database']]
  File "/path/to/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 207, in __getitem__
    conn = backend.DatabaseWrapper(db, alias)
  File "/path/to/site-packages/sqlany_django/base.py", line 447, in __init__
    super(DatabaseWrapper, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/path/to/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 102, in __init__
    self.client = self.client_class(self)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

2. Regarding `CursorWrapper`

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "/path/to/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 47, in handle_inspection
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
AttributeError: __enter__
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it on monday. But I think I can accept it, Django 1.8 solved it, but I have to find out, how to run two Django projects on one IP address. Don't you possibly know some link where is it described or should I rather ask another question?

Comment: I don't know about that.

Comment: Did you get this to work with Django 2.2.4?

Comment: I tried it now and it's better. Now there is an error `Unable to inspect table 'xxx'
# The error was: subclasses of BaseDatabaseIntrospection may require a get_constraints() method
`

Comment: Can you share the stack trace? (Or do you use TeamVIewer? I don't have a Sybase DB to test with.)

Answer (score 1):

Replaced typecast_decimal() with decimal.Decimal()

change base.py code like to

```
Database.register_converter("decimal", decoder(decimal.Decimal))
```

and in utils.py you can return

> decimal.Decimal()

maybe help to you

Comment: What is the line number in `utils.py`? I don't understand here, what to replace...

Comment: correction: Should I change this line `Database.register_converter(Database.DT_DECIMAL, util.typecast_decimal)` in `base.py` to `Database.register_converter("decimal", decoder(decimal.Decimal))`?

Comment: yes and in your utils.py if you dont have typecast_decimal function created and in your expression import  Decimal from  decimal

Comment: And you can see  here   https://github.com/maxirobaina/django-firebird/issues/102

Comment: And what should I replace by what in `utils.py`?

Comment: util.typecast_decimal to  decimal.Decimal()

Comment: Thanks, I will try it on monday.

Comment: In `my_app/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py` there is not `typecast_decimal`.

Comment: change in base.py and use as function on utils.py

Comment: like this : https://github.com/django/django/commit/f3e350d6318c20d0d5e2f53f278b9dcc326e1d74#diff-1132e403debb86cff5e5dd3366985796