# Connect to Sybase database from Django

Tags: django, sybase

I tried to connect to `Sybase` database from `Django` using `sqlanydjango`, but
I have [stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708712/module-django-db-backends-utils-has-no-attribute-typecast-decimal). One answer saying that

```
sqlany-django is no longer maintained; it was last updated in May 2016.
```

What is the other possibility to connect to `Sybase` database?

OS `Ubuntu 18.04`

django `2.2.4`

Answer (score 1):

`Sybase` is no longer maintained and it's not supported by Django. I recommend using one of the [supported databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/databases/):

- PostgreSQL
- MariaDB
- MySQL
- Oracle
- SQLite

Personally, I would recommend using [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) - I think it's the most advanced database. If you use it, I would recommend using version 13, since version 14 is still new and I think it's not officially supported by Django yet. It's always a good practice to use the previous major release. Also with Django, I recommend upgrading to the latest major release only about 4 to 6 months after its initial release. So for today, this means using Django 3.2 (latest minor release, currently 3.2.11).

You can use [django-environ](https://pypi.org/project/django-environ/) to define the database you are using in settings.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [freetds module](http://www.freetds.org/). GitHub repository was active 5 days ago, it aims to provide support for sybase and MSQL Server.

I used it with MSQL

You can download it from [there](http://object-craft.com.au/projects/sybase/download.html), and installing with the instruction on [this link](http://object-craft.com.au/projects/sybase/install.html) (Sybase python module website)

Then you can test your installation using [these steps](http://object-craft.com.au/projects/sybase/sybase/node6.html)

You can also try different Django version.

If this doesn't show anything wrong, and Django still won't connect to your DB, you can try to edit Django's source files so the ImproperlyConfigured exception doesn't raise (REALLY REALLY RISKY, DO A BACK UP OF YOUR DB) or migrate your Sybase to a supported database.

Comment: freetds throws this error `File "/home/pd/pd_videowebapp/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django_pyodbc/base.py", line 98, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Django %d.%d is not supported." % DjangoVersion[:2])
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Django 2.2 is not supported.
`

Comment: These are my settings `'sybase_database': {
        'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'db_name',
        'USER': 'user_name',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '10.60.1.18',
        'PORT': '2638',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'FreeTDS',
            }
    }`

Comment: are you stuck with that specific version of Django ?  Did you try [these steps](http://object-craft.com.au/projects/sybase/sybase/node6.html) to check your installation ?

Comment: I can't install it on Linux, because [this](http://object-craft.com.au/projects/sybase/sybase/node7.html) link is dead. For more info, I'm using Python 3 and pip.

Comment: Could you please provide details of your django settings (with FreeTDS and pyodbc)? And how you installed it? I'm trying it now with django 1.8. I can't connect with FreeTDS even to msssql, which works with `ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server`. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but I can't share it because we stopped using sysbase

Comment: Thanks. It's already [solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72259266/653379)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pyodbc.
To install this.

Pip install pyodbc

```
import pyodbc
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(‘DRIVER={Devart ODBC Driver for ASE};Server=myserver;Port=myport;Database=mydatabase;User ID=myuserid;Password=mypassword;String Types=Unicode’)
```

For reference:-
https://medium.com/@sharma.jayant1992/best-way-to-connect-python-with-sybase-database-76445713efaf